# Correct ascending order of Patch Numbers gathered from database

Tags: sql, mysql

So I have Patch numbers that I need to get from database in correct order, and this is the sql query that I use right now

```
SELECT Patch_No FROM info ORDER BY Patch_No ASC
```

here is how those patches look after using this query:

[image]

So patches are like 1.0.0.23, 1.0.0.99, 1.0.0.100, 1.0.0.104, 3.00 so they would be in this order. It is getting mixed up with 1.0.0.100, 1.0.0.104 and so on the rest is fine.

Comment: 1.0.0.99 is less than 1.0.0.100 because you're ordering by number. `0.1` is less than `0.99`.

Comment: It looks like it is sorted alphabetically, not numerically.

Comment: are there any simple fixes maybe in php? so I wouldn't have to change the values in my database to 1.0.0.099 etc?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `+0` to make mysql treat `Patch_No` as a column of numbers and not strings

```sql
SELECT Patch_No FROM info ORDER BY Patch_No+0 ASC;
```